# Poincaré constant for a ball (circle)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, integral-inequality

I've been recently looking for a best possible Poincaré constant for a particular domains $\Omega$ (it's related to my previous question [Unique weak solution to Helmholtz equation on a square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1557969/unique-weak-solution-to-helmholtz-equation-on-a-square)) for $W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$-functions.

If $\Omega = (0,1)^2$, than I was able able to prove that
\begin{equation*}
||u||_2^2\leq \frac{1}{16}||\nabla u||_2^2,\quad\forall u\in W_0^{1,2}((0,1)^2).
\end{equation*}

I was wondering what happens if $\Omega=B(0, 1)\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$? I can circumsribe a square about the circle and I get that
\begin{equation*}
||u||_2^2\leq \frac{1}{4}||\nabla u||_2^2,\quad\forall u\in W_0^{1,2}(B(0,1)),
\end{equation*}
but I believe there must be a clever way how to do it. I don't necessarily need the best possible constant (i.e. the smallest one), but I'm looking for some reasonable estimate (without some magic tricks) that gives a constant that is as small as possible.

Thank you for any help:)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The key to what you're looking for is Rayleigh's theorem, which states that 
$$
\lambda_1 = \min_{0 \neq u \in W^{1,2}_0(\Omega) } \frac{\int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2 } {\int_\Omega u^2},
$$
where $\lambda_1 >0$ is the principal eigenvalue of the Laplacian with Dirichlet boundary condition, i.e. 
$$
\begin{cases}
-\Delta u = \lambda_1 u &\text{in } \Omega \\
u = 0 & \text{on }\partial \Omega.
\end{cases}
$$
Why is this useful?  For any $u \in W^{1,2}_0(\Omega)$ such that $u \neq 0$ the Rayleigh theorem tells us that 
$$
\lambda_1 \int_\Omega u^2 \le \int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2,
$$
but this inequality also trivially holds for $u=0$ and thus for all $u \in W^{1,2}_0(\Omega)$.  Thus $1/\lambda_1$ is the best constant in the Poincaré  inequality since the infimum is achieved by the solution to the Dirichlet problem.  Now, the crucial feature of this is that for a ball, namely $\Omega = B(0,r)$, we can explicitly compute the eigenfunctions and eigenvalues of the Laplacian by using the classical PDE technique of separation of variables.

It's here where I will trail off and let you go discover the rest of the details on your own.  If you get stuck you can either look in Strauss's book *Partial Differential Equations: An Introduction*, or you can hit up google.  For instance, I think [this](http://www.math.toronto.edu/courses/mat394h1/20139/LE.html) link has what you're looking for.  The key point is that you will find a connection with all sorts of beautiful classical mathematics related to Bessel functions and their zeroes (I can't help but throw out a reference to the tour-de-force by Watson, *A Treatise on the Theory of Bessel Functions*).

Let me know if you'd like more help or extra references.  I'm happy to help!

Comment: Thank you for you help! I believe this will help me. I'll go through it. Thank you